# Moving Rows via Checkboxes

Tags: google-apps-script, onclick

I have a WS in Google Sheets which has 3 tabs (sheets).

1-) Has a form to submit new tasks and a filtered view of the tasks with checkboxes next to each entry based on the current month via FILTER function.

2-) Has the form entries copied from the Task Entry Form in the above sheet or tab.

3-) Has the list of completed tasks and that should be moved from Entries sheet when the checkbox (in 1st tab above) is clicked.

I have been trying to testing scripts that I could find via Google or YouTube.  However, it doesn't work properly.  As I am a newbie, I cannot diagnose where the problem is.

The problem is;

i-) Because in the first tab, the tasks are a filtered view, checkbox does not work properly.  So, in order to make the connection, I have added another column in the Entries table, where the results come from the Task Entry Form as shown in the screenshot.[Task Form Entries with the Additional Status Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8WAE.png)

After that I connected this Status column to the checkboxes.  So, when I click on a checkbox, it turns the corresponding cell in Entries tab to TRUE.

```
function moveChecked2(){
const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const ss = sh.getSheetByName("Entries");
const targetSheet = sh.getSheetByName("Completed Tasks");


let data = ss.getRange(3,1,ss.getLastRow()-1,5).getValues();
let out = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
if (data[i][4] == true){
out.push(data[i]);
ss.clearContents();
data.splice(i,1);
i--;
}
}
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,out.length,5).setValues(out);
}
```

The above code was working fine. However,stopped working and gives an error saying that "out.length" in the last line of the code should be at least 1.  IIt was originally working fine and when one checkbox is clicked, it was moving.  Now, although I check one or more, it gives the same error.  I tried to hard code and typed 1 instead of out.length.  Didn't work, either.

If this code worked, I would insert a drawing as a button and assign this script to activate.

After several hours of trial and error, I decided to try onEdit function.  I have found a few different codes, which works with a dropdown value.  I tried to customize them so that they can work when the checkbox is clicked.  Couldn't managed to do, either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function moveChecked2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Entries");
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Tasks");
  let vs = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 2, 5).getValues();
  let out = [];
  let d = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    if (vs[i][4] == true) {
      out.push(vs[i]);
      sh.deleteRow(i + 3 - d++)
    }
  }
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, out.length, 5).setValues(out);
}
```

Here's an onEdit that performs it one row at a time as you check the checkboxes

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Entries" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Completed Tasks");
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastRow()).copyTo(tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1));
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, for your first piece of code, it gives an error for the last line and says that 

"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')
moveChecked2."

And for the second code, for the following line, it gives an error again;

const sh = e.range.getSheet();

And the error is;

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit 

What possibly could be wrong ? Both are gives an error about the range.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I test both of  these on some of my data and they both work.  On the top one the error suggest that tsh is not defined so may be there's something wrong with sheet name.  And the second is  an onEdit so you cannot run it without supply the event object that is supplied by the onEdit trigger.  It's common mistake that newcomers make

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying back.  Well, I don't know how but the first script started to work again.  So, I can click and select one or more checkboxes and when the script runs, it moves to another sheet.

However, still the onEdit thing does not work.  As you said, I happened to be aware of the newcomer fault and tried to test the script.  It says the script finished, but nothing happens.  I even tried to change the order of the script within the editor, but no avail.

Anyways, if I can make it work, it would be super. Otherwise it is still okay and thanks for the help again.

Comment: I am assuming that the checkboxes are in column 5 and the go from row 2 and below. I also asssume that you are using the standard true/false value of "TRUE" and "FALSE" although it is possible to change them as long as you change the code as well.  As I've said I tested both function on my test data.  If you wish you may supply test data in a table and I can try to test with that.  Be aware that I will not follow links to spreadsheets

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I have been very busy with some other features in my spreadsheet and with some other codes.  Anyways, this code also started to work interestingly.  Having said that I was wondering whether there could be an issue of cookies so that the code does not work at the very beginning but then it starts to work.  Anyway, thanks a lot for the help.